# Google OAuth2.0 - Windows phone 7

Tags: wpf, silverlight, oauth-2.0

Experts,

I'm new to OAuth,

I'm writing an small App in windows Phone 7, I'm using OAuth2 for google contacts, I need to get the initial URL API (1) to get the Token

1) https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&scope=https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&client_id=CLIENT_ID&hl=en-US&from_login=1&as=NEW_AS&pli=1

I got the success code, and when I'm trying to use this
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?access_token=TOKEN_CODE
but I'm getting 401 error back,

Can you please advice, what mistake i'm going.

I've taken Twitter OAuth example as base, and doing modifications.

## CODE

```
        var uri = new Uri(url);
        var request = BuildOAuthWebRequest(url, null);
        MakeGetRequest(callback, request);   



    private static HttpWebRequest BuildOAuthWebRequest( string url, string realm)
    {
        var header = new StringBuilder();
         var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
       return request;
    }
    private static void MakeGetRequest(EventHandler<OAuthEventArgs> callback, HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        var asyncState = request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback((asyncRes) =>
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = null;

            try
            {
                //request has returned
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asyncRes);
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        var token = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        callback(null, new OAuthEventArgs() { Response = token });
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (WebException we)
            {
                string t = new StreamReader(we.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                callback(null, new OAuthEventArgs() { Error = we, ErrorMessage = t, IsError = true });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                callback(null, new OAuthEventArgs() { Error = e, ErrorMessage = e.Message, IsError = true });
            }
            finally
            {
                if (response != null)
                    response.Close();
            }
        }), null);
    }
```

Comment: Post your code we have no idea how your sending these requests.

Comment: Google provides a .NET library (with source) for accessing their GData apis; They do all the OAuth stuff for you.

Comment: Thanks Boo. I will check .net api.